# Gulp babel completes but code is not updated

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, gulp-watch, gulp-concat

As soon as I hit save, gulp babel finishes tasks with message printed in the terminal. But code is not updated in the browser. I have a local Nginx serving my gulped files. I have to reload multiple times to get the updated code.

My gulp file:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'src/app.js',
        'src/app.controller.js',
        'src/**/*.js',
        'libs/*.js'
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(concat()('app.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

//other tasks here (css, assets etc)
...

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch([
        'src/**/*.html',
        'src/images/**/*',
        'src/fonts/**/*',
        'src/**/*.json'], ['assets']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'sass', 'assets', 'watch']);
```

Gulp default is what I run.

However, without gulp-babel (for ES5) it works fine. I have to reload only once in the browser to get the updated code. I have tried hard refresh, even enabled the "disable cache while devtools is open" option in Chrome but no luck.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you should add `return` before `gulp.src` in your `js` task

Comment: [check out this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) , it may be because of presets are missed

`.pipe(babel({
            presets: ['babel-preset-es2015']
        }))`

Comment: @Vinodhan what does babel-preset-es2015 do? Couldn't find a description

Comment: @ArjunU. think that because of missing to define the babel([options]) that doesn't work as you expected. I have given `presets: []` as an example. [check this options list](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) :(

Comment: @Shvelo Gulp wasn't completing instantly. It was taking time. Adding `return` solved my problem as I  had multiple streams and now the message is printed post the task completion. Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return` before `gulp.src` so Gulp can know when the task is completed

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'src/app.js',
        'src/app.controller.js',
        'src/**/*.js',
        'libs/*.js'
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(concat()('app.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```